# Text with maths in R

Tags: r, text, plot

I need to include a text caption on a graph in R. I basically want to include a regression coefficient (R^2) - which I have done with the code below

```
text(-8, 2,  bquote(R^2 == .(round((summary(fit1)$r.squared),2))))
```

But now I would like a few changes. I would like the R^2 to be in italics, and to add other text information.

I could make the R^2 italics like this

```
text(-8, 2,  expression(italic(R^2)))
```

But is there a way to do this using bquote() so I can include the regression coefficient as well?

A second question would be how can I also include other text in the same caption.

For example I have also tried this code to plot some text before the R^2 - but here the maths doesn't work at all

```
text(-9, 2, paste("Linear Regression \n R^2" , round((summary(fit1)$r.squared),2)))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just wrap it with `italic`

```
text(-8, 2,  bquote(italic(R^2) == .(round((summary(fit1)$r.squared),2))))
```

and to add some strings

```
text(-8, 2,  bquote('Linear Regression'~italic(R^2) == .(round((summary(fit1)$r.squared),2))))
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
set.seed(425)
x <- sample(10, 10, replace=TRUE)
y <- sample(20, 10, replace=TRUE)
fit1 <- lm(x~y)
plot(x, y, xlim = c(0,10), ylim = c(0,20))
text(8, 2,  bquote('Linear Regression'~italic(R^2) == .(round((summary(fit1)$r.squared),2))))
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! As a final issue - is there a way to use \n and put the R^2 on a new line?

Comment: @lily23 Perhaps you need `text(8, 3,  'Linear Regression');
text(8, 2,  bquote(italic(R^2) == .(round((summary(fit1)$r.squared),2))))` (for the example I showed)

Comment: Thanks - that'll do the job =)